# Docker-compose for spring boot microservice structure

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices

i just tried to build some microservices with spring boot. And wanted to deploy my eureka server on docker.
But i currently get the error:

```
PS D:\2. repo\services> docker-compose build --no-cache
[+] Building 26.9s (14/14) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-slim                                                      0.5s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11-slim                                              0.6s
 => [build 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11-slim@sha256:04f8e5ba4a6a74fb7f97940bc75ac7340520728d2fb051ec  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 808B                                                                                           0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-slim@sha256:93af7df2308c5141a751c4830e6b6c5717db102b3b31f012ea29d8  0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                       0.0s
 => [build 3/6] COPY pom.xml .                                                                                              0.1s
 => [build 4/6] RUN mvn dependency:go-offline                                                                              24.4s
 => [build 5/6] COPY eureka-server/src /app/src                                                                             0.1s
 => [build 6/6] RUN mvn package                                                                                             1.5s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar ./eureka-server.jar                                             0.0s
------
 > [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar ./eureka-server.jar:
------
failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1619314829/app/target: no such file or directory
PS D:\2. repo\services>
```

This is my structure:

```
- services
    --> | eureka-server
        - Dockerfile
        - pom.xml
    - pom.xml
    - docker-compose.yml
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
    eureka-server:
        image: "eureka-server"
        container_name: "eureka-server"
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: "./eureka-server/Dockerfile"
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
```

And this is my dockerfile:

```
# Use a base image with Java and Maven installed
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11-slim AS build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the POM file
COPY pom.xml .

# Download the project dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline 

# Copy the source code
COPY eureka-server/src /app/src

# Build the project
RUN mvn package 

# Create a new image with a smaller base image
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built JAR file from the previous stage
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar ./eureka-server.jar

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 8761

# Command to run the application
CMD ["java", "-jar", "eureka-server.jar"]
```

Maybe someone can help my why this docker runs into the error of not finding the jar.

When i run mvn package in the cmd i get this output:

```
D:\2. repo\services\eureka-server>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.portshare.services:eureka-server >----------------
[INFO] Building eureka-server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\2. repo\services\eureka-server\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\2. repo\services\eureka-server\target\eureka-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.023 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-08T21:43:29+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\2. repo\services\eureka-server>
```

Comment: You're `COPY`ing `*.jar` files from a directory `/app/target` which seems not to be existed. Check the build command (`mvn package`) and find out where it generates the build artifacts.

Comment: @msrumon
so when i generate it in cmd with "mvn package" it gets stored in /target.

Comment: @msrumon I added the output of the mvn package in the question. You can see there it is getting created in the /target folder. I can also see it when going into that folder.

Comment: I think the compiled `.jar` file is in `/app/src/target` directory. It can be confirmed by seeing the file structure of your project. I'd suggest to add the following debug instruction after `mvn package` in your *Dockerfile* to be sure the exact location of it: `RUN ls -l /app && echo "---+++---" && ls -l /app/src`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the COPY directive in your dockerfile to

COPY --from=build target/*.jar ./eureka-server.jar

Comment: Sadly i also get the error here. 
```
=> [build 6/6] RUN mvn package                                                                                                                                                                             1.6s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build target/*.jar ./eureka-server.jar         
 > [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build target/*.jar ./eureka-server.jar:
failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount91878562/target: no such file or directory
``` 
But it tells me build runned successfull

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the directory of `jar` file is wrong, or not exist. I have encountered this type of error for many times, you can try to add some statements that output the directory structure of your project in the container, make sure that the `/target` folder in your project is exists.
Another possibility for this problem is that wildcards (*) are not supported in the path. You can try to use the sepcific name of the `jar` file with varbiles. For example: `MyProject-SNAPSHOT-${VERSION}`, the pattern of filename can be setted in the `pom.xml` file.

Since I've had this problem before, these are the two approaches I've tried before.